# SpringBoot insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory-leaks

I'm executing more than 30000 REST requests in 5 threads (6000 per thread) to Swagger running on top of Tomcat inside SpringBoot and getting next error after 35 minutes of running:

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 16384 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   The process is running with CompressedOops enabled, and the Java Heap may be blocking the growth of the native heap
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
#   JVM is running with Zero Based Compressed Oops mode in which the Java heap is
#     placed in the first 32GB address space. The Java Heap base address is the
#     maximum limit for the native heap growth. Please use -XX:HeapBaseMinAddress
#     to set the Java Heap base and to place the Java Heap above 32GB virtual address.
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2985), pid=24780, tid=58785
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.11+9) (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)

Command Line: -Xverify:none -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Xms2g -Xmx10g com.CamelSpringBootApplication

Host: Common KVM processor, 16 cores, 28G, Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Time: Mon May 31 15:40:22 2021 CEST elapsed time: 2122.252495 seconds (0d 0h 35m 22s)
```

SpringBoot application is running on Ubuntu VM which should have 64GB of RAM, but value is dropping like crazy as you can see on the next graph.

I'm missing some information and don't know the reason of this. Where I'm making a mistake? What exactly is taking so much memory and how can I release the memory in runtime?

Memory comes back to 64GB only after restarting the VM.
After I start SpringBoot application again, RAM starts dropping down even before running the REST requests.
I need to support as much as possible REST requests, preserve RAM and stop SpringBoot app from crashing.

[image]

Update:

These are the results of collected heap dump. I've loaded heapdump.bin into heaphero.io. I would appreciate any tips based on this results.

[image]

Comment: You could look at the heap dump generated while the application crashed (or create one during high memory consumption manually). You can use this in order to see what requires lots of memory.

Comment: With which tools can I do that? Is there any I can run directly in terminal inside the VM?

Comment: See [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-heap-dump-capture) on how to get heap dumps. You can then use tools like the eclipse memory analyzer tool in order to analyze it.

Comment: I've updated the question with the heap dump stats. I will try to clean strings after usage.

Comment: I didn't manage to find an exact reason/s for this memory behaviour, but it's very likely possible that the main reason for this is in my code which should be edited and optimized. Another possible reason of memory leak is that Tomcat in Spring Boot needs to handle a quite large number of requests (that should be properly closed if not done automatically) in short time and should be configured properly for that task.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hazard a guess, **you may be outrunning garbage collection**
After counting a quarter of the number of that 30000 or so, call
System.gc();
to notify collecting the garbage.
[This i wrote](http://windsolarhybridaustralia.x10.mx/httpoutputtools-tomcat-java.html) sits in the RAM and requires a small garbage management check and counter.

Comment: I've added quite a lot of System.gc() calls in the code and before them set Variables (mostly ArrayLists, Maps and JSONObjects) to null, but it looks like Java is ignoring those calls and memory is still going down.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have allocated sufficient heap size, even if you have 64 GB RAM for your Linux machine, you need to externally extend its default capacity as per applications incoming traffic.

You can increase heap size for spring boot application inside pom.xml file as follows -

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <jvmArguments>-Xmx4096m</jvmArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I've extended -Xmx up to 16 GB but didn't help.